# how to fix no atribute 'name' error in a list of files in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, file, streamlit

i am using streamlit with python in order to allow user to upload multiple files than to show the content as a dataframe.

But first i need to check if its **csv** type or **xls**, and dislay the type and name.

The problem is that when it comes to check what is the file type it crash and display the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'
Traceback:
File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\streamlit\script_runner.py", line 333, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 766, in <module>
    main()
File "f:\AIenv\streamlit\app2.py", line 300, in main
    file_details = {"filename":data.name,
```

**Note if i upload a single file the script run with no error.**

## code:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

def main():

   if st.sidebar.checkbox("Multiple Files"):
          data = st.sidebar.file_uploader('Multiple Excel files', type=["csv","xlsx","xls"], 
          accept_multiple_files=True)
          for file in data:
              file.seek(0)
    
   elif st.sidebar.checkbox("Single File"):    
          data = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload Dataset",type=["csv","xlsx","xls"])
        
   if data is not None:        
          # display the name and the type of the file
          file_details = {"filename":data.name,
                           "filetype":data.type
                        }
          st.write(file_details)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: With multiple files, your `data` is a list, but you're treating it like a single file.

Comment: so you mean if i concat these multiple files into 1 file i can come across this error ?

or what else can i do ?

Comment: No, I mean what do you expect `file_details = {"filename":data.name, "filetype":data.type }` to do when `data` is not a file, but a list?

Comment: @khelwood so the list will have the same type  because after i get the file details i want to read these file so if they are csv i will use `pd.read_csv` else `pd.read_excel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access name and type of list of files if "multiple files" is checked. I suggest unifying of your 'data' structure and making it always a list. Then you have to iterate over it:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd

def main():
    if st.sidebar.checkbox("Multiple Files"):
        data = st.sidebar.file_uploader('Multiple Excel files', type=["csv","xlsx","xls"], 
            accept_multiple_files=True)
        for file in data:
            file.seek(0)
    
    elif st.sidebar.checkbox("Single File"):    
        data = st.sidebar.file_uploader("Upload Dataset",type=["csv","xlsx","xls"])
        if data is not None:
            data = [data]
        
    if data is not None:
        for file in data:
            # display the name and the type of the file
            file_details = {"filename":file.name,
                            "filetype":file.type
            }
            st.write(file_details)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: your answer did not work and still display the same error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: If i choose the multiple files  the system crash 
And display the error about `no attribute name`

Comment: Rechecked now: I click on "Multiple Files", new button "Browse files" appears. After clicking that button file choice dialog is opened. I selected two .xlsx files and after submitting saw an expected result: filename and filetype in a form of dictionary are listed on the page. Can't confirm your problem, please make sure that you copied my answer exactly and no other code parts can affect this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`data` in this case should be a `list` type (you can check with `type(data)`).

What you could do is change:

```
   if data is not None:        
          # display the name and the type of the file
          file_details = {"filename":data.name,
                           "filetype":data.type
                        }
          st.write(file_details)
```

To:

```
if data is not None and len(data) > 0:
  st.write("filename {} | filetype: {}".format(data[i].name, data[i].type) for i in range(len(data)))
```

Comment: what if i need to read the uploaded files  like `pd.read_csv` or `pd.read_excel`?

Comment: That seems like a different problem then what the question is asking (if I understood correctly). If you need help with that, there is a really good guide here: https://blog.jcharistech.com/2020/11/08/working-with-file-uploads-in-streamlit-python/, though I'd imagine you could write some logic to determine the file type uploaded (via a `regex` in the `filename`), and then make the correct `pandas` call from that

Comment: i already saw this guide  and its only deal with single file my problem is with multiple files